# PhpStorm Remote Debugger (Xdebug) for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I've been trying to setup remote debugging through PhpStorm with Xdebug for the best part of the day but have been unable to get it working despite my best efforts.

When I go to validate the deployment configuration, I get the error seen below:

> "Specified URL is not reachable, caused by: 'Request failed with status code 406'"

[image: Validate Debugger Configuration error]

Following the [JetBrains troubleshooting guide](https://%20https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/validating-the-configuration-of-the-debugging-engine.html#troubleshooting-validation-results), I created a `test.php` file and put that in the public folder on the server and I was able to access that. My mappings also basically match what they have in the bottom of their guide.

I was able to install/enable Xdebug on the server by going to **Select PHP Version** in cPanel and enabling xdebug under **Extensions**.

I've added the following to the site's `.htaccess` file (found in `/public`):

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
php_flag zend_extension=xdebug.so
php_flag xdebug.mode=debug
php_flag xdebug.remote_enable=1
php_flag xdebug.remote_autostart on
php_flag xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
php_flag xdebug.remote_port=9000
php_flag xdebug.max_nesting_level=512
php_flag xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
php_flag xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

I cannot find anyone else with the same error so I don't know where the problem lies. Is there something wrong with the configuration? Do I have to change PHP settings? Xdebug settings?

Before I attempted to setup remote debugging, I was able to get local debugging working through Homestead and a lot of my settings match where applicable. I'm just honestly not sure where I'm going wrong and I would appreciate any and all help in this matter.

According to a `phpinfo()` dump on the server, here are some relevant details:

- PhpStorm: 2021.3.2
- Client OS: Mac OS Monteray 12.3.1
- PHP: 7.4.29
- Server OS: Linux
- Xdebug: v2.8.0

##### UPDATE:

I scrolled down on the `phpinfo()` page after submitting this question and noticed that the Xdebug variables are listed with their defaults. It appears that the `php_flag` in the `.htaccess` file isn't working. Is that a correct assumption or will it not affect the info dump?

[image]

##### UPDATE 2:

I have adjusted my `.htaccess` file and now Xdebug variables appear to be getting set correctly. It still hasn't resolved the 406 error however which should rule out Xdebug as the cause unless I'm still missing options.

[image: Updated phpinfo]

Comment: 1) Enable Xdebug log and try to debug. Then check the log. It's a starting point. 2) How is your router/firewall is doing? Is it enabled to allow incoming connections on Xdebug TCP 9000 port? Remember: it's Xdebug that connects to a client and not other way around (common mistake).

Comment: With your set up Xdebug will try to make an outgoing connection to the detected IP address (because of `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`) -- this will be an outgoing connection for your server. But for your local Mac (router) this will be an external incoming connection which most likely will be blocked/not allowed by your router/firewall by default. Consider using SSH tunnel (PhpStorm Help has an article for that).

Comment: As for 406 error: no ideas TBH. I suggest you check your web server and (S)FTP logs to see: 1) was the test script uploaded by PhpStorm (and to what location) 2) do you see the request in the web server access/error log. 3) Anything in PHP error log that may be happening in that test script?..